# issue with duplicating record in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

When I search any record by **chapter number** then it works.

But the problem is when I select **chapter number 1 or 2** from drop-down and the search all records included in that chapter.

It displays all records included in 1,11,21,31...or 2,21,12,...like this.

I know I wrote '**like**' there that's why it happens.  But when i write " **=** " operator that I commented in my code that also didn't work for me.

What will be the perfect query to solve this problem?

**My Code:**

```
   <?php
         include("conn.php");         
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $name2=$_POST['chapter'];        
         $sql="SELECT distinct * FROM $user WHERE question like '%".$name."%' and Chapter like '%".$name2."%'";
  // $sql="SELECT * FROM $user WHERE question='$name' and Chapter='$name2'";
         $result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {           
   ?>
```

Comment: Can you specify what happens when you give '='

Comment: either there are other chars in the fields or the combination of question/name and chapter/name2 is not in your table

Comment: @Mani:Thank you mani for rpl. Ok When i give '=' symbol ,it will not search any record.

Comment: I have question and chapter field in my table.

Comment: Then as specified by others you may not have combination of values you search for. And i guess question is a char column and chapter is number. If so try using like for question and '=' for chapter.

Comment: I know its horrible, but you could keep the `LIKE` and add another `WHERE` clause which determines that the length of `Chapter` is the same length as your `$name2` ?
Also for this you would remove the first `%` in your `LIKE` statement for the `Chapter` clause

Comment: I hope this is a mistake in the example and its not the case of changing 
`$sql="SELECT * FROM $user WHERE question='$name' and Chapter='$name2'";`
 to 
`$sql="SELECT * FROM $user WHERE question='%".$name."%' and Chapter='%".$name2."%'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be interested to see what the type of 'Chapter' is in the returned query, and try to see why it is that the equality comparison doesn't work.
If the typing is straightforward (i.e. it really is just plain old strings), then I'd be looking for whitespace characters or something like that which is foiling the equality comparison.

Similarly, I'm wondering whether it's the equality on the 'Question' that is messing up your alternate query.

At a guess, try one of the following:

```
$sql="SELECT distinct * FROM $user WHERE question like '%".$name."%' and Chapter like '$name2'";

$sql="SELECT distinct * FROM $user WHERE question like '%".$name."%' and Chapter='$name2'";
```

Oh, and you should really do something about escaping those parameters properly to avoid any nasty SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks  a lot chamila. Your 1 query is worked for me.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part of the first query:

```
Chapter like '%".$name2."%'
```

If `=` doesn't work, then I can think of two things.  The first is that `Chapter` is really a list, probably a comma delimited list.  The second is that there are extraneous characters in the database.

If `Chapter` is really a list, use `find_in_set()` instead:

```
find_in_set($name2, Chapter) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I never used find_in_set before.So can you write my above code with find_in_set() If possible??

Answer (score 0):

You directly use $_POST variables in your SQL query which makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please take a look at this page for ways around that: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html. You should use either `mysql_real_escape_string` or prepared statements (better). The best solution would probably be to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Also if you want a better answer, please format your question so it can be easily read, include example inputs, outputs and database contents and make sure your code is properly indented.

All I can assume now is that your database field probably contains more than the data you want to match. Leading/tailing spaces or something?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your query is in this section

like '%".$name."%'

Just remove % sign from your whole query where you have wrote and check your query may work
properly.